# 'international-space-station' as a tag synonym to 'iss'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I know this would be trivial or redundant on a site centered around space exploration, but I believe [iss](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iss) should have what it stands for as a tag synonym [international-space-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-space-station).

Most people visiting this site are probably familiar with the iss, but I think it would be good to have for the odd visitor that isn't used to the acronym, yet seeks or wants to make a question about it.

In general, I think it would be good to have the full name as a synonym to the acronyms, since the excerpt is not searched when typing in the tags bar of a question.

For example [environmental-control-and-life-support-system](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-control-and-life-support-system) as a synonym to [eclss](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclss)

Comment: @JCRM eclss is the Environmental Control and Life Support System, which is specific to the ISS. the tag life-support is for life support as a whole

Comment: Eclss is not specific to the iss.

Answer (score 3):

All right, I added the tag synonym [international-space-station](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/international-space-station)!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, we should try having the acronym tag <-> synonym relation the other way around more often.

While "ISS" is a well known acronym, this field is famous for generating an enormous amount of hard-to-understand acronyms.

Even though things like [environmental-control-and-life-support-system](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-control-and-life-support-system) is a bit on the lengthy side, [eclss](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eclss) tells me absolutely nothing.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but we should also not make tags of extreme length. that being said, i have no idea how one would shorten the tag to get something in between.